# Is it possible to set the properties on the command line for sourceanalyzer?

Tags: fortify, sourceanalyser

I'd like to change the scan properties on only one project for our build server. I've found tons of references for what to change in the various fortify ".properties" files, but I don't want to make any changes that will be universal.

Is it possible to either define these on the command line or, even better, specify a specific .properties file to use only for the current scan?

Note, this has to be via the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for any property that you want to change put it in the appropriate command line (translate vs scan) in the following format:

```
-D<property key>=<property value>
```

for example

```
sourceanalyzer -b mybuild -Dcom.fortify.sca.fileextensions.sql=PLSQL *.sql
```